# var is casted to int even when result should be decimal

Tags: c#

I know this is a really basic question, but please explain why this is.

```
var number = 7 / 2; // number is 3
decimal number = 7 /2; // still number is 3
```

Why isn't the number 3.5? Why is it always casted to int? Because the numbers are both int? This works when you cast one of the numbers to decimal.

Comment: You are dividing two integers, the result is always an integer.

Comment: The denominator is 2 (change to 2.0) so the compiler truncates the fraction part of the results.

Comment: The expression *7 / 2* (type `int` / `int`) will evaluate to the integer value 3 as it is using integer division.

Comment: If you want a numeric literal to be treated as decimal, use the suffix `m` after one of the numbers that you're dividing (just as Rene and Manfred have pointed out)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *literals* `7` and `2` both are interpreted by the compiler as `int`. So the division is an *integer division*  resulting in an `int` of value `3`.

Using the `var` keyword, the compiler infers the correct type from the expression, leading to `number` in the first line being of type `int`.

In the second line, you explicitly declare `number` as decimal, so the `int` returned by `7 / 2` is casted to `decimal`.

---

If you want the result to be `decimal`, you should use the correct literal ending with `m`:

```
var number = 7/2m;
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `7/3` is `(int)7/(int)3`. 
If you want to get a [decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx), use `7m/2m`

Comment: it's enough to do `7/2m`

Comment: @GiladGreen yep, that would suffice.

Comment: @GiladGreen or `7m/2`